# How can I get which products are not saleable in configurable products in magento?

Tags: magento

I can get it through this code :-

```
$allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
foreach($allProducts as $p)
   if($p->isSaleable())
endforeach;
```

But the way I want is....like I have 1 configurable product in which I have 2 colors white then it's related sizes like s,m & l so total I have 3 products of combination of white to s,m & l & same way Blue & it's related s,m & l. So finally I can say I have 6 products.

Now the thing is White->s & l and Blue->s & m these products are out of stock and the problem is that all product's name are same i.e. T-Shirts so now how can I get to know which combination products are out of stock?

Any Code Please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Javier for your valuable support :)

The way I wanted the output, Here I am posting the solution :-

```
/* FOR CONFIGURABLE PRODUCTS */
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
if($_product->isConfigurable())
{
    /* FIRST GET ALL ATTRIBUTES OF CONFIGURABLE PRODUCT */
    $attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($_product);
    foreach($attributes as $att)
    {
        $pAtt = $att->getProductAttribute();
        $array_attribute_code[] = $pAtt->getAttributeCode();
    }

    /* NOW LOOP THE PRODUCTS & GET COMBINATIONS WHERE PRODUCTS ARE OUT OF STOCK */
    $allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
    foreach($allProducts as $allProduct)
    {
        if(!$allProduct->isSaleable())
        {
            for($i=0;$i<count($array_attribute_code);$i++)
            {
                echo $allProduct->getAttributeText($array_attribute_code[$i]).' ';
            }
            echo "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

Try the above code & get pair like output like White s then beneth White l then beneth Blue s

Important to tell you that I have implemented this code in my module's .phtml file.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand properly you want to know which size & colour is out of stock? So, in that `if ($p->isSaleable)` you can should be able to check the colour and size as such:

```
echo $p->getAttributeText("color");
echo $p->getAttributeText("size");
```

If that doesn't work try:

```
$p->getResource()->getAttribute("color")->getFrontend()->getValue($p);
```

Other way is having the size & color in the short description, or having some kind of SKU code to be able to distinguish them. Ie. MYPRODUCT46. Where 4 can be mapping to a colour and 6 can be mapping to a size).

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Javier, First of all Thanks for your help :)

Now the thing is that thing I were knowing that we can get it by calling getAttributeText function but the thing is Only I/you know that it is color & size :) haha   That was the real problem so I wanted those in pair. Now I have got solution to it after 4 5 hours of thinking & hit & miss :) I am going to post whole solution in half an hour.

But many thanks Javier for your valuable answer :)

Comment: Not sure if I'm following, but then I guess `$p->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray` might be of help. Anyway, glad that you found a solution :)